# VB.NET LINQ Method Syntax disallows implicit conversions from 'Integer?' to 'Integer'

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

Compare weirdness when working with LINQ and Entity Framework.
I want to retrieve an ID from my DB and I get this weird message.

I could simply fix it as you can see but I want to **understand** why this happens.

**Question**:

Why do I get this error message even if I check with "HasValue" or I use "FirstOrDefault"? It can't be null in my opinion but I obviously miss something.

[image: Code and Error]

Comment: Please paste in your actual code. Screen shots are hard to work with.

Comment: Even if **you** check `HasValue`, the `strict` policy doesn't care. Have you tried simply casting it to Integer? `user.setID(DirectCast(cctUser.OPX_Rechte, Integer))`. Since you know the property has a value, it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Yes I could simply cast it but I didn't like to simply do it without understanding why I had to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `.Value` if you are 100% sure the `Integer?` has a value.

> Why do I get this error message even if I check with "HasValue"

Entity Framework just uses the objects you give it. It can't create a new object where OPX_ isn't nullable.

Comment: Can accept your answer in 10 Minutes. Thank you learned something.

Answer (score 2):

the setOpxRights function presumably takes an Integer as a parameter and Option Strict On won't allow an Integer? to be implicitly converted to an Integer.  If you are sure that it will always have a value, pass in cctUser.OPX_Rechte.Value

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is not perfect, we can see that OPX_Rechte will have a value because of the where statment, but for the compiler you are just using a the object cctUser that have an Integer? and it needs an Integer.